# what lightbulb can I use in this 250V 100W light fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, bulb

I am located in the United States and have a light fixture in my kitchen w/ the following parameters:

250V, 100W
model: K512GU
not sure what this part is: 2/250

Can I use this 60W bulb in this fixture: http://a.co/eMM1v4R? More generally, do I have to use a 250V, 100W bulb, or can the voltage on the bulb differ, or can the wattage differ, or can both differ?

Pictures of the existing bulbs (which stopped working) and the info in the light fixture are attached.

[image: bulb]

[image: some info]

[image: some more info]

Comment: the linked bulb is GU24, 24mm pin spacing. I'd guess you need a GU10.

Comment: Which country are you located in?

Comment: @jon United States

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers you have found are the *maximum ratings* of the *socket*.

The wattage of the bulb, if incandescent, must not exceed 100 W but may be less.

The voltage of the bulb must match the voltage supplied by the electric service, which is almost certainly whichever of either 120 or 240 volts is standard for your country. The voltage rating of the socket is irrelevant. Check the old bulb for a voltage marking.

Answer (score 3):

Those types of ratings are always for the upper limits for wattage.  You can always go smaller on the wattage. In this case I'm certain that the voltage is an upper limit regarding that socket also. However, you are going to want to match the voltage of the lamp you took out.  That is the only thing that will work.  You can always go lower on wattage.

Answer (score 3):

This bulb is a GU10 which means the pins on the bulb are 10mm apart (just less than 0.5 inch). They come as halogen type and also as the new LED type which are very energy efficient but more expensive to buy. The halogen ones get very hot and the LED ones stay pretty cool.

USA uses 110-120 volt standard for regular house wiring.  Your 250 volt socket is capable of 250 volts if used in other countries that use 250 volts.  Just take the bulb to the store and get a GU10 which are 110-120 volts in the USA. Typically the halogen bulbs are 50 watts and the equivalent LED is about 6 watts but puts out the same amount of light.    You can even get these at Walmart.